# How to set ComboboxItem Cursor property to Hand

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

Maybe this was asked before but I have not found this question.

I want to set the `ComboboxItem` `Cursor` property to `Hand`.

I tried the following but doesn't recognize `ComboboxItem` in `TargetName="CombxBoxItem"`:

```
<ComboBox.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="CombxBoxItem" Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ComboBox.Template>
```

I think I'm close so I would appreciate a little bit of help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignComboBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignComboBoxItemStyle}">
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very close of what I want. It shows the `Hand` but if I move the `Cursor` out of the ComboBox doesn't close it and the `Cursor` is still a `Hand`. How can I do to improve that behavior?

Comment: It should revert back to the default cursor as soon as you close the `ComboBox` by clicking somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work.  Could you see if it will work for you?

```
        <ComboBox>
            <ComboBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ComboBox.Style>
            <ComboBox.Items>
                <ComboBoxItem>Item 1</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Item 2</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Item 3</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Item 4</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox.Items>
        </ComboBox>
```

Comment: That code changes the style of the ComboBox and I'm using MaterialDesign. I didn't mention that. Anyway doesn't work for me. Cursor is still an Arrow.

Comment: I couldn't solve this yet. There's any other alternative to try?